# Why am I getting "Binder has not been registered" when Spring Boot app from JAR generated from Gradle

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I have used `gradle init` to create a project then added Spring Boot. However when I run `gradle assemble` then `java -jar app\build\libs\app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-all.jar` I get

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.1)

12:51:48.345 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder has not been registered
```

What am I missing? My build.gradle looks like this...

```
import org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {

            name '...'
            url "..."
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '8.1.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.1'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.jrgleason'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = "17"
    targetCompatibility = "17"
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
    localDatabase
    awsDeploy
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "..."
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'com.h2database:h2'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:4.0.3'
}

mainClassName = 'com.jrgleason.App'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.jrgleason.App'
        )
    }
}
```

How do I run this as a jar file? `gradle bootRun` seems to work with no problem